# VBA code for generating QR codes, but where does the code begins?

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

For work, I have to generate some QR code with info in it.
Therefore, I checked on internet and found this "already made" QR code generator :

https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only

It's very nice, and works quite well.

I'm trying to integrate it into my VBA sheet to do data treatment before using the code to create the final QR code. (Nothing complex)

here is how it looks like :
[image]
The 4 cells "B4 to B6" get the entry data which are encoded or not, depending on the checkboxes, then the result it written in the column D.
Each cell content is stacked in a variable, and this variable is given to eat to the QR code generator :

```vb
Public Function GenerateQRCode()

Dim CurrentWS As String

UserDataRange = "B6:B9" 'The cells in which the data to be encoded are stored
InputDataRange = "D6:D9"    'the cells with the encoded (or not) values
InputCell = "A4"    'the cell where the text to be encoded in the QR code has to be put

'encode the text depending on hte value of the cell behind the chek boxes
For Each cell In Range(UserDataRange)
   If cell.Offset(0, 1) = True Then
       EncodedText = EncodeDecode.Base64EncodeString(cell.Value)
       cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = EncodedText
   ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 1) = False Then
       cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = cell.Value
   End If
Next

Range(InputCell).ClearContents
DataToEncode = ""

'puts the text in the input line with dashes between each value
For Each cell In Range(InputDataRange)
pouet = Range(InputDataRange).Address

   If DataToEncode = "" Then
       DataToEncode = cell.Value & Chr(10)
   Else
       If cell.Address = Mid(Range(InputDataRange).Address, InStr(1, Range(InputDataRange).Address, ":") + 1, _
       Len(Range(InputDataRange).Address) - (InStr(1, Range(InputDataRange).Address, ":") - 1)) Then

           DataToEncode = DataToEncode & cell.Value
       Else
           DataToEncode = DataToEncode & cell.Value & Chr(10)
       End If
   End If
Next

Range(InputCell).Value = DataToEncode

End Function
```

My concern is that "whatever cell I modify in the whole workbook, it lunches the QR code generator."

I wanted to give a condition at the beginning of the code like `If cell A4 is modified, lunch the code`, but I don't even achieve to understand what makes the code start and how the data are gathered...

My best guess is that this is the beginning of the code :

```vb
Public Function EncodeBarcode(ShIx As Integer, xAddr As String, _
                code As String, pbctype%, Optional pgraficky%, _
                Optional pparams%, Optional pzones%) As String
  Dim s$, bctype%, graficky%, params%, zones%
  Dim oo As Object

  Call Init
  If IsMissing(pzones) Then zones = 2 Else zones = pzones
  If IsMissing(pparams) Then params = 0 Else params = pparams
  If IsMissing(pgraficky) Then graficky = 1 Else graficky = pgraficky
  If IsMissing(pbctype) Then bctype = 0 Else bctype = pbctype
```

But how is it started? O.o

I thought a line like `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)` followed by a control of the value of "target" was mandatory... 
Here, it looks like magic to me :(

How does `xAddr` gets the address of the cell I clicked? Magic again...

I would like the execution of the code to happen only when I click the button I created. (it generate some infinite loops and excel shuts down :/ )
Or, if not possible, I would like it to be executed only when the data in the cell A4 are modified.

Thank's for your help :)

Comment: Actually pleople here probably won't download a macro enabled file from a suspect source (espacially if it comes from the dark lord himself ;). So according to [ask] you must incude everything that is needed to understand in the question itself. Can you please include how you run the code? Is it run by a formula? If so please show how you used that formula.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ "So according to How to Ask you must incude everything that is needed to understand in the question itself" Well, ok... But you'll regret this... ^^,

Comment: Before you post your *entire* code please read [mcve] :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Well, basiaclly, you don't need my code, the original QR code generator is enough, I didn't modify anything (I understand nothing of this mess ^^,). i'd just like to be able to control its execution instead of having it being executed each time a cell is accessed (not even modified, double clicking a cell, then pressing "enter" makes the code run and this from any sheet... :-/ )

Comment: Is Git Hub considered as a reliable source? Or I need to copy this 2000+ lines code?

Comment: If you run the code by a formula, then you must remove the formula and run the code by giving the same parameters using VBA I guess. Something like `EncodeBarcode Range("B10"), Range("B10").Address, Range("A4"), 51, 1, 0, 2` in VBA instead of the formula.

Comment: As we cant see the code that produces QR codes, does it have a `Class` module? If so check in there. There might be something in there that is catching `On_Chnage` event

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Well, in fact, to lunch it, I just modify the value of the cell A4, and it runs by itself... the "xAddr" is a specific VBA variable that always take the address of the last modified cell?

Comment: @Zac You didn't download the code from GitHub? I'll past it here... But that's 2K lines... And, no, there is apparently no class module :-/ Ok, I can't, the code is too long...

Comment: Is there a sheetcode? In VBA project if you doubleclick on the sheet name, is there a sheet_change code?

Comment: It must be a custom formula in cell B4 (I think, looking to the picture...) and it is automatically calculated if the `Application.Calculate = True`.
In order to use the button, you must see the function called by the formula and create a call using the same parameters.
I do not have time right now, but I will download the project in less then one hour and I will come with more details.

Comment: @FaneDuru Uuuuuh, yes, I forgot that thing, there is this : =EncodeBarcode(CELL("SHEET");CELL("ADDRESS");A4;51;1;0;2) & "TPI N°  & B9" in the cell B4, so, this is what call the function when any cell is pressed? :/

Comment: @zepeu: Yes. But you must see the EncodeBarcode VBA procesure and try to understand its parameters in order to reproduce them. Only in this way you can call it from a button code. It looks my initial estimation was not valid. I still cannot download the file in discussion...

Comment: @FaneDuru I did, but this code is way more complex than I can understand ^^, But, I got it, and it works now :)

Comment: @zepeu: Does it place the QR Code where you want, according to a specific cell address?

Comment: @FaneDuru I didn't try to control this, it is where it was before, and I'm ok with that ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [CELL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) function is **volatile** it recalculates on **every** calculation (not only on calculation in cells it depends on). That means `EncodeBarcode()` calculates on **every** calculation too (because it is using the `CELL()` function in its parameters).

> *A Volatile Function is one that causes recalculation of the formula in the cell where it resides **every time Excel recalculates**.
>   This occurs regardless of whether the precedent data and formulas on which the formula depends have changed, or whether the formula also contains non-volatile functions.*

If you remove the `CELL()` function and replace it with hard values

```
=EncodeBarcode(1;"B4";A4;51;1;0;2)
```

it doesn't re-calculate the barcode on every cell change. But it does only re-calculate the barcode if the cell it depends on changes (it this example cell A4).

Comment: But, I am afraid (without seeing the code) that this format cannot be used in VBA directly. The VBA function must be seen and the call has to be so constructed in order to match all of them...

Comment: "of them" = its parameters... :-)

Comment: @FaneDuru This solution is formula only (no VBA involved). The only issue why it did not work before was because it was using the volatile `Cell()` function.

Comment: @FaneDuru As Peh said, my main concern was that the code was executed every single time any cell of the whole document was modified... Now, it's executed only when I call it like a nice small obedient program ;-)
This whole code is way too much complex for my current knowledge, I even had problems to understand what made it begin :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Yes, It is correct. But writing "B4" or "xx" the result will be the same. The code has a trick using `Type(Application.Caller)'... If it's a range the formula uses the cell address and position (Left, Top) in order to put the QR Code on the Top Left corner of the cell where the formula is. In order to make it functional from VBA (too), the function will bel called: `EncodeBarcode ActiveSheet.Index, "$B$4", ActiveSheet.Range("A4").Text, 51, 1, 0, 2`. A private variable 'rName' will  take the value of `xAddr' and in function `sub bc_2Dms` will use `Set xRange = xSheet.Range(rangeName)`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: after `Else` (when `Type(Application.Caller)` returns 'Error' instead of 'Range')...

Comment: @FaneDuru Well, I didn't take a deeper look into the code further than how the parameters of the function were declared. And actually the formula in my answer worked (and solved the probelm). Actually the only issue of the original formula was that it used a volatile function which made it recalculate over and over.